# TinyMCE: Center dialog window (WindowManager.open) in Editor

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, tinymce, tinymce-4

When I use editor.WindowManager.open to open a dialog window in tinyMce, it is centered on the screen.
I would like it to be centered inside the Editor.

How to approach this? Can I control the window location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by adding centering CSS dynamically to the web-page Head when the form opens.

In the "editor.windowManager.open" function of the dialog, I added this code:

```
id: 'xxx-dialog',                           
onopen: function() {                                
   // Forcibly center dialog                                
   if ($("head #added-xxx-dialog-CSS").length == 0) // only once
   {
      $("#xxx-dialog .mce-dragh").remove(); // disable dragging of dialog
      var mceHeight=$(".mce-tinymce").height();
      var mceTop=$(".mce-tinymce").position().top;
      var thisHeight=$("#xxx-dialog").height();
      var newTop=mceHeight/2+mceTop-thisHeight/2;
      $("head").append('<style id="added-xxx-dialog-CSS"
      type="text/css">#xxx-dialog {top:'+newTop+'px !important;}</style>');                                 
    }
}, // etc...
```

This code only centers the Dialog vertically, as in my application the Dialog is centered horizontally automatically anyway, but it is very easy to add a few more lines in the same way to center it horizontally as well.